# Is it good practice to use if block in while case statement in getopts

Tags: shell, getopts

```
    #!/bin/bash
while getopts ':s:r:' c
do
  case $c in
    s) if [ "$OPTARG" -ge 0 ]; then
        echo "value is $OPTARG"
       else 
         echo "enter value greater than 0";;
    r) echo "something";;
   
  esac
done
```

Or should i remove if block from case statment and put it after the case while loop?

What is the good practice? Any documentation I can refer?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it good practice to use if block in while case statement in getopts

Subjectively: sure, why not. Except you are missing an `fi`.

> should i remove if block from case statement and put it after the case while loop?

Subjectively: it would be preferred. For me.

> What is the good practice?

I believe a common way is to set only variables within options parsing, then write sanity checks after options are parsed. But it's not an universal way of doing it and it may be preferable for some applications to do some logic while parsing options. As always, the ultimate answer is: "it depends".

> Any documentation I can refer?

Linux man pages and POSIX Programmers manual. [man 1p getopts](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getopts.1p.html) has an excellent example that shows how to set flags first and then write sanity checks.